# locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration not called

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, compass, calibration, heading

I have a simple iOS app which uses the heading. However as the accuracy is very bad (10 to 25 degrees), I implemented the locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration function. However it never gets called. Here is my code:

```
    ...
    locmanager = [CLLocationManager new];

    [locmanager setDelegate:self];
    [locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locmanager setHeadingFilter:kCLHeadingFilterNone];
    [locmanager setHeadingOrientation:CLDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft|CLDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {

        [locmanager startUpdatingLocation];
        [locmanager startUpdatingHeading];
    }
    ...

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading*)newHeading
{
     // This one gets called
}

- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager
{
     // This one does NOT get called
     NSLog ("Here");
     return YES;
}
```

What should I do to get the compass calibration ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Official Documentation:

> Core Location may call this method in an effort to calibrate the onboard hardware used to determine heading values. Typically, Core Location calls this method at the following times:
>
> > The first time heading updates are ever requested
> >
> > When Core Location observes a significant change in magnitude or inclination of the observed magnetic field

So it's entirely possible that your calibration if already fine and need not be set. Note that this method will never get called in simulator.

Try using MKMapView with MKUserTrackingMode.FollowWithHeading and see if calibration window appears. Your delegate might still not get called, because MKMapView calls it through it's own private location manager delegate.

You may also try turning off Compass Calibration in Settings -> Location Services-> System Services on your device.

Answer (score 0):

1. see `CLLocationManager` `requestAlwaysAuthorization` method
2. add required keys to your **info.plist** file (now required)

   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
       bla bla why we use GPS.
       NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
       bla bla why we use GPS.
3. must be setup on main UI thread !!